# Finding the dual of this primal LP.

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems

I am going over sample questions from a sample exam, and I got stuck on the following question. I need to determine the dual of this LP:

$min: c^Tx + d^Tu \\
s.t: Ax + Du = b\\
x \ge 0$

$A$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrix, D is an $m$ by $p$ matrix. So this is what is throwing me off when I try this question. I know that the dual of a regular LP like:

$min: c^Tx \\
s.t: Ax = b \\
x \ge 0$

becomes

$max: b^Ty \\
s.t: A^Ty \le c$

However, in this case, if I try applying the same type of strategy, I get stuck as follows:

$max: b^Ty \\
s.t: A^Ty + D^Ty \; (\le, =) (c, d)$

The problem is that the dimensions of $A^T$ and $D^T$ don't agree anymore... so I tried adding an extra set of dual variables $z$... but it doesn't really get me anywhere, since $b$ is a vector in $R^m$ so any dual variables would have to be of that dimension as well.

Any hints/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try deriving it. I doubt you can use direct formulae for this case. (Just out of curiosity, is it a 2 stage Stochastic Programming Problem?) I present an explanation for a simpler case. 
\begin{align}
\min &\quad c'x\\
Ax&=b\\
\end{align}
In order to take the dual, you first take the Lagrangian. 
\begin{align}
L(x;\lambda)&= c'x-\lambda '(Ax-b)\\
\nabla_xL(x;\lambda)&= c-A'\lambda=0\\
\end{align}
Thus, we got the constraint for optimality- $A'\lambda=c$.

Now, objective function.
\begin{align}
L(x;\lambda)&= c'x-\lambda '(Ax-b)\\
L(x;\lambda)&= c'x-\lambda 'Ax+\lambda 'b\\
L(x;\lambda)&= (c-A'\lambda )'x+\lambda 'b\\
L(x;\lambda)&= 0'x+\lambda 'b\\
L(x;\lambda)&= \lambda 'b\\
\end{align}
Now, for when we deal with the Langrangian, we have a $\max \min$ operator.
Thus, the objective function is:
\begin{align}
\max_{\lambda} \min_x L(x;\lambda)&= \max_{\lambda} \min_x \lambda 'b\\
\max_{\lambda} \min_x L(x;\lambda)&= \max_{\lambda} \lambda 'b
\end{align}
That is all, we have our objective function : $\max_{\lambda} \lambda 'b$ and the constraint $A'\lambda=c$. 
You can work out the algebra along the same lines for your specific case, I don't think the results will be as clean (maybe they are).